# How to use onKeypress event in a textbox

Tags: node-red

I'm currently working with a node-red demo for conversation service,the question is submitted by hitting a send button, I created a function to do the same when the user press "enter" but it does not work... can someone help me to see what is going wrong this is the current code:

```
  <div id=id_botchathistory>
  </div>
  <div>
      <form>
        <label for="id_chattext">Ask your question here:</label>
        <input type="text" name="chattext" id="id_chattext" onkeypress="javascript:onkeypress()">
        <br/><br/>
      </form>
      <button onclick="javascript:onChatClick()">Send</button>

  function onChatClick() {
    var txt = $('#id_chattext').val();
    chat('You', txt);
    invokeAjax(txt);
  }

  function onkeypress(){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var txt = $('#id_chattext').val();
    chat('You', txt);
    invokeAjax(txt);
  }
  }
```

Thanks in advance for all the support.

Comment: There is no 'event' argument in onKeyPress function.

Comment: if (e.keyCode == 13) , where is the 'e' coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have some syntactical mistake and try to use addEventListener for event binding** as:

```
  document.getElementById("id_chattext").addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var txt = $('#id_chattext').val();
   e.preventDefault();
   alert(txt);
 }
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s9y6qpmv/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot... the event fixed and I also change the function to onkeydown